# How should I reward xp to my players in my game of Dark Heresy in Stars Without Number?

Tags: game-design, experience-points, stars-without-number

I'm about to start running a game of Stars Without Number hacked to play Dark Heresy. My players will be creating their characters in a few days. But in my hack, I have so far not a word on what they will be rewarded xp for. I've said that they will be rewarded Fate Points (narrative Bennies) for completing goals and missions, but I am almost entirely lost on how to reward experience.

I'm not sure whether goals would suit this game considering the kind of assumed nature of the Goals of the Inquisition, nor Beliefs and Instincts. My main thought on the subject is that one of the themes of the campaign is how these Inquisitorial Agents are changed by their work and consequently, I was considering some fashion I could reward them for gaining Madness (from Silent Legions), Corruption (from Dark Heresy) and Faith (my own creation in the same vein as the other two, except the wyrd is related to obsessive zealotry). But I'm not sure how?

I am of the school of thought that reward is the most important part of a roleplaying game system and I don't want to get this wrong. Out of every part of the hack, I think this is the most vital. Please, any help you could provide I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: This sounds more like it's just the final part of your homebrew design, and not so much about a technique for handling things at the table, so I'm retagging this game-design and removing the gm-techniques tag.

Comment: Just to be clear: you mean that you're abandoning the normal method SWN uses for awarding XP per adventure?

Comment: And if you are abandoning the normal SWN method, a brief discussion of *why* you've chosen to abandon it would be helpful.